# How much overhead would be caused by a Sprite-kit layer over a performance intensive graphics app?

Tags: ios, metal

I have an app that I am working on that ends up using all available resources on the CPU and GPU on older (iPod touch 4) devices. It is built in OpenGL and Metal and chooses the one that works best on the device.

I need to now add the interface which involves some buttons and simple animations. I am considering adding the capability to render and handle quad textures into my engine (this wouldn't be too difficult) but I was wondering how much overhead I would experience if I instead had SpriteKit or UIKit or another framework draw over my app instead.

Would there be a lot of overhead just by having an additional layer and additional framework?

Is there perhaps a better framework for this?